# MySQL update / replace serialized data without corrupting it

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, drupal, mariadb

I've been tasked with running a find / replace on one word throughout an entire Drupal 8 site. It's a mixed case word like "wOrd" that I need to swap with "WORD".

Drupal 8 is running MariaDB, so the REGEXP_REPLACE function has come in very handy. Example:

```
UPDATE node__body SET body_value = REGEXP_REPLACE(body_value, 'wOrd', 'WORD') WHERE BINARY body_value REGEXP '[[:<:]]w[[:upper:]]rd[[:>:]]'
```

I'm using BINARY to only ensure case sensitivity and only match instances of "wOrd".

So enough preamble - some tables use BLOB in lieu of TEXT for storing long strings of *serialized* data, as seen in Drupal 7 and a lot of other CMS's and various frameworks. My question is whether it's possible to handle manual update / replace functionality in serialized data without having to filter it through code to unserialize it first.

In this particular case, the length of the serialized field does not change so I can run the update / replace without any problems. There's no distinction made between "wOrd" and "WORD" as far as I can tell. However, I've run into many situations where a client suddenly wants to make site-wide changes where I'm not lucky enough for the string length to match.

Is it inevitable that I'd have to write a utility to handle serialization? If so, can people please share their take on it?

If you need me to elaborate on anything please just let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The term "serialization" is too broad to suggest something particular for your case. It could mean tons of different ways.
Like, imagine the blob data is zipped - thus any replacement made would ruin the whole thing.

So if you know the way serialization happens, and you're pretty sure the data is mapped 1:1 - then you can handle it same way as raw text.

But if you don't (and it seems so) - then the only truly safe way to do it would be, yes, deserialize-make change-serialize back.

PS Other option would be to just deserialize the whole thing, the whole DB, once.

Comment: In this case, it's a LONGBLOB field with plain text. Drupal 8's internals handle the serialization, which I assume boils down to serialize() unserialize(). It looks like `a:12:{s:4:"uuid";s:36:"14eb8e72-bd6d-47c4-ab92-c297d81a287f";s:8:"langcode";s:2:"en";s:6:"status";b:1;s:12:"dependencies";a:3:{s:7:"content";a:1:{i:0;s:56:"block_content:basic:37272863-0339-4b0c-81dc-9476ea17c52f";}}` - I had to cut it off due to length.

Comment: as far as I get, your target is going to look like this: s:4:"wOrd", 
and you're intending to make it s:4:"WORD", is that correct?

Comment: Right. My main question is how to handle it if I needed to change it to something that doesn't fit nicely into the serialized string. Such as if I had to change "word" to "the word". Sounds like my only option would be to change `s:4:"word" to s:8:"the word"`. Otherwise it's no longer serialized correctly and becomes corrupted. I've figured out the "wOrd" to "WORD" issue - the number of strings and the length of the string I'm changing in the DB field does not change.

Comment: Right, here's the thing: you're trying to intrude into the stuff you not really knowing all about.

Apart from the case you mentioned (when the field length gets changed) - what if, say, it calculates a checksum for serialized stuff? 
What if external search indexes are involved? Etc., etc.

And even in the case you mentioned: you need to implement at least a part of the serializer mechanism (e.g. keep the field length in conformance) - but it IS implemented already!

So, again, it turns out your only SAFE option here - is to deserialize - go through - serialize - put back in place.

Comment: I'm aware that I'm making some possibly intrusive changes : ) Good point on the checksum. I'll dig into the back end more and see how updates are handled. Thanks for the info.